Contrasts in one-way anova
I am watching one lecture about ANOVA and lecturer gave 3 examples for possible hypothesis for the data:

For hypothesis 3 ($\mu_2 = \mu_1 - 3*\mu_3$) coefficients for contrast don't sum up to zero $(-1 + 1 + 3 \neq 0)$. Can we say in this case that it is contrast? If not, then what is it? And can we check in this case this third hypothesis for orthogonality with hypothesis 1 like it was made on the slide $(a * c)$?
UPDATE. I also aded slide with definition of contrasts:

Also, article on wikipedia
So, my question is the same. If coefficients for hypothesis don't sum up to zero, is it legitimate to check if it is orthogonal to some other hypothesis or not?

Hi. Welcome to CV. This is a MathJax-enabled site. Please use this
facility to typeset your mathematical expressions for better
legibility. For a quick guide, check this Meta CV post:
Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated.

Why must contrasts sum to zero?  After all, in the most basic situation the null hypothesis is $H_0:\mu_1=0$ whose coefficients sum to unity, not zero!

@whuber Does the term "contrast" have different meanings / uses? I know "contrast" to mean a linear combination of model parameters but take a look at what the [tag:contrasts] tag says: "contrast is a linear combination of parameters with coefficients summing up to zero".

Thinking more about this, is the difference between (a) contrasts used to represent categorical variables where the "coefficients sum to 0" constraint is necessary to deal with overparametrization, and (b) contrasts used to express and test hypotheses (as linear combination of parameters)? Both of these are mentioned by the tag description but are not the same thing?

@dipetkov Thank you -- you are correct.  I have employed the term in the broader but perhaps unusual sense of any linear constraint on the parameters.  This suggests either the exercise writer was using the term in that generality or there's a typographical error.  Because its result is the intended one--$(-1/2,1,-1/2)$ is orthogonal to $(-1,1,3)$--a typographical error looks unlikely.

These are linear hypotheses: they can be written as linear combinations of the group means ${\mu_i}$. So yes it's legitimate to check whether two linear combinations (vectors in a vector space) are orthogonal. This is a mathematical property. Not sure whether the orthogonality says anything interesting about hypotheses H1 and H3. And see these threads about the sum-to-zero constraint: Sum-to-zero constraint in one-way ANOVA, What does the sum to zero constraint mean?

@dipetkov The orthogonality makes it easy to test the hypotheses.  In particular, the sequence of testing doesn't matter.

Thanks @whuber. If two hypotheses are orthogonal in one parametrization (here in terms of the group means $\mu_i$), is it guaranteed that they are orthogonal in any parametrization? I tried to express these hypotheses in terms of $\beta_i$ with the usual dummy coding and then H1 and H3 are no longer orthogonal. (Or I got the math wrong.) I tend to think that answers shouldn't depend on the parameterization. So if we test three hypotheses, that's three hypotheses to adjust for no matter the order of calculations.

@dipetkov It depends on what kinds of reparameterizations you allow.  Orthogonality is preserved by orthogonal transformations, by definition.  Any other transformation will not preserve all mutually orthogonal sets of vectors but might preserve some of them.  So, a good way to review what you did would be to write down the matrix that describes the change of coding and check whether that matrix is orthogonal.

"it's legitimate to check whether two linear combinations (vectors in a vector space) are orthogonal". If so, then why this idea of "contrasts" was introduced at all? Why do we bother at all whether coefficients sum up to 0 or not? What makes "contrasts" special or interesting or useful?

@Helios They implement natural, standard comparisons in ANOVA.
